# JBoss AS7: Web Service connection refused

Tags: web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, jboss7.x

I am using ProcessBuilder on JBOSS AS7 to run an external JAR which then calls Endpoint.publish() to create a JAX-WS Web Service. I am using a Stateful bean to access the Web Service afterwards.

The service itself runs fine, I imported the WS-client proxy classes via wsimport and I can access the WSDL via browser or soapUI.
But when I try to access the Web service on the server, JBOSS outputs "connection refused". I even tried Debug mode but without gathering any useful messages.

I already disabled the firewall but no dice:

```
 javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://localhost:4045/WebService/WebMethod?WSDL'.: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

System: JBOSS AS7.1.0.Alpha2, Windows, localhost

jboss log:

```
08:26:01,572 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.

08:26:01,573 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:149)

08:26:01,574 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:141)

08:26:01,574 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)

...

08:26:01,603 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.

08:26:01,603 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:94)

08:26:01,603 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:203)

08:26:01,603 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:147)

08:26:01,603 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    ... 158 more

08:26:01,604 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://localhost:4045/WebService/WebMethod?WSDL'.: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

08:26:01,604 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source)

08:26:01,605 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)

08:26:01,605 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)

08:26:01,605 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:239)

08:26:01,605 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:186)

08:26:01,605 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:92)

08:26:01,605 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1)    ... 160 more

08:26:01,606 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

...

Answer (score 1):

Try to run Jboss server by adding the property -b 0.0.0.0 in the file run.bat like follows:

```
standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Stephen84s' answer:](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/131175)

> You need an echo server running on your system, which is provided by
>   most UNIX machines and runs on port no 7.

and from the same source

> To check if your Vista box has one running just hit telnet localhost 7
>   , if it shows connection refused or could not connect, then it means
>   you box does not have an echo server, and hence your program will not
>   work and thats the reason I feel for your ConnectException exception.

You mentioned that you turned the firewall off. Then, you must have the port [wrong](http://www.coderanch.com/t/207717/sockets/java/resolve-java-net-ConnectException-Connection).
Try to run your software as localhost, for instance to the port 4000:

```
echoSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4000);
```

Comment: This does not apply because the port was open and available. it also worked when I manually launched the Webservice.jar and then tried to connect via the Webservice Client on AS7. It looks more like a configuration problem or limitation of AS7 rather than a network problem.